# Знак вопроса в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, спп, сложное-предложение, вопрос

Если объединить вопросительное предложение с уточняющим его невопросительным предложением, то знак вопроса можно поставить в конце второго?

*У вас нет пилы, чтобы разрезать доску?*

Или:

*Вы всё понимаете, о чём здесь написано?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без вопросительного знака эти предложения будут просто повествовательными и не смогут выразить необходимый посыл:
*У вас нет пилы, чтобы разрезать доску.

Вы всё понимаете, о чём здесь написано.*

Поэтому знак вопроса не только можно, но нужно поставить.

> 4. **Вопросительный знак** ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточной: *Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия?* (Остр.); *Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело?* (Ч.)

Источник: [§ 2. Вопросительный знак](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88) (справочник Розенталя).